# Disable CSS transitions for a single style?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

It's pretty easy to enable CSS transitions for a single style, but is it possible to disable them for a single style?

The usual method for single-style transitions is:

```
div
{
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

but what I'd like to do is set a global transition, then disable it for a single property. Maybe something like this?

```
div
{
    transition: 0.5s opacity 0s;
}
```

Is that possible in any way?

**EDIT**
I don't want to disable ALL transitions for an element, I want to disable ONE transition for an element. i.e. I want all properties to transition EXCEPT opacity.

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/QSJXV/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It seems that you can emulate the needed behavior by setting a very short transition-duration for that one property ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gMnnJ/)):

```
transition: all 3s ease, background-color .01s linear;
```

Answer (score 7):

I solved this. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/QSJXV/1/

It works exactly how I thought it should, except I was missing a comma. Correct code example:

```
transition: 0.5s, opacity 0s;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s, opacity 0s;
```

Comment: The zero duration seems not to work in Fx 23 (Win 7). But some small but non-zero value like .01s seems to do the trick. I suppose this may have something to do with `dom.min_timeout_value` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#Minimum.2F_maximum_delay_and_timeout_nesting)).

Comment: This should be accepted answer. 0.01s is meaingless. Most of the browsers are supporting this now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the :not pseudo-selector to exclude those elements which you mark with a class that shouldn't have the transition.

```
div {
  opacity: 1.0;
  ...
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
          transition: all 0.5s;
}

// Change state for example
div:hover:not(.disable-transition) {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.disable-transition {
   // Manually maintain the opacity so there is no change
   opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO! OP wants to disable transition for a single CSS property (still for the same HTML element)

Comment: Ah I see... could you modify this answer to include the transitions you DO want. I don't believe there is a way to selectively disable specific properties within the transition.

Comment: Assume that I want to transition on all properties except one. I don't think there's a way either, but that's why I ask.

Comment: See if the edit makes sense for you... I think I am understanding.

Comment: I actually just solved it. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18238807/331043