# How can I override CSS transitions for individual css properties?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a component whose source I am not in control of. It has a transition rule that looks like this:

```css
.3rd-party-component {
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

I am using the component in a way that I do *not* want specific properties to transition at all. I don't want `width` or `height` to transition for example. But I do want everything else to continue to transition as designed.

I understand that I could apply a new rule in my source code that looks like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18238823/20294314

```css
.3rd-party-component {
  transition: all 2s ease, width 0s none;
}
```

but that's only because I know what the original 3rd party code looks like. If the 3rd party transition were updated to `3s`, then I would have to mirror that change in my rule in order to maintain parity. I don't want to be responsible for all of the transition code, I just want to turn some of them off.

Does CSS have any way to express that? It might look like this:

```html
<style>
.original-rule { /* this is not in my source code, it's somewhere else */
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
.target {
  transition: width 0s ease; /* i want this to override only the width transition */
}
</style>

<!-- now i can apply my override class to the 3rd party component -->
<div class="original-rule target"></div>
```

Targeted `transition` rules seem to override the original rule entirely. But then I lose all of the transitions I actually want.

```js
function appendComponent() {
  const newComponent = document.createElement("span");
  newComponent.classList.add("third-party-code");
  const main = document.getElementById("main");
  newComponent.innerHTML = "3rd Party Component";
  main.appendChild(newComponent);
}

function appendOverrideComponent() {
  const newComponent = document.createElement("span");
  newComponent.classList.add("third-party-code", "my-code");
  const main = document.getElementById("main");
  newComponent.innerHTML = "3rd Party Component";
  main.appendChild(newComponent);
}

function change() {
  const elements = Array.from(
    document.getElementsByClassName("third-party-code")
  );

  elements.forEach((element) => {
    element.classList.toggle("different");
  });
}
```

```css
/* here is a simulation of the off limits 3rd party code */

.third-party-code {
  background: green;
  transition: all 5s ease;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  min-width: 20%;
}


/* here is a simulation of my overrides */

.my-code {
  transition: width 0s ease;
}


/* this is just so that the transitions are visible */

.different {
  background: pink;
  min-width: 100%;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<p>Create an original component and an override component, then click "Change Styles" to see how the targeted override loses all of the 3rd party transition code.</p>
<button onClick="change()">Change Styles</button>
<button onClick="appendComponent()">Original Component</button>
<button onClick="appendOverrideComponent()">Component with Overrides</button>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: If you want no transition at all you could use `transition: none;` and if needed you can add importance to your rule `transition: none !important;`

Comment: “I just want to turn some of them off” - how are you finding the ones you want to turn off?

Comment: @AHaworth arbitrarily. it looks weird for the width to be animated, so i don't want it to be animated.

Comment: @JDawwgy i do want transitions. i want the component to have most of the intended transitions, for example color, background, and so on. those look great. but i don't want others. height and width for example. i know i can write a new rule that specifically says which things i want transitioned and which ones i don't. but then i have to accept responsibility for the entire set of transitions on this component. i don't want to do that. i just want to opt out of some and for the rest defer to the 3rd party rule (which happens to be "all")

Comment: If you can overwrite certain transitions like the height and width, I don't see how the values of those transitions increasing would warrant a need for your overwrite rule `transition: width 0s none;` to be remade?

Comment: @JDawwgy the problem is that if my code applies the rule `transition: width 0s none;` then that rule overrides `transition: all 2s ease;`. I have to choose all the 3rd party transitions or none. I'm looking for an alternative, or a way to avoid that dilemma. I've added a runnable snippet to demonstrate my point. I want a way to keep the background transition and throw away the width transition, without having to write `transition: background-color 2s ease` in my source code